# How to handle progress bar in JSF2.0 Mojarra

Tags: jsf-2

I'm making 3 web service calls during page submit. These are all synchronous calls. I want to show a kind of progress to the user in my screen with a status like, "first service started", "first service call completed", "second service started", "second service call completed" etc.

I'm using JSF 2.0 Mojarra. Can any one suggest approach for this?

Comment: @BalusC I can see you edited this question. Can you please throw some light on this? In fact I'm waiting eagerly for your answer...

Comment: You can use [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf) for inplementing the progress bar itself.

Comment: can you join those two [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041564/custom-progress-bar-info-is-not-working-with-jsf2-0-mojarra-and-jquery)?

Comment: I was able to manage with JQuery-ajax by polling for required data. Issue resolved. thanks @BalusC